# ways to tag characters in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tags

Is there an alternative way to index characters in text other than the one in the example below?

```py
text.tag_add('highlightline', '1.1', '1.2')
```

For example, it would be useful to index them as if they were in a list or a 2D matrix.
Where each row in the text corresponds to a row in the matrix and each cell of the matrix contains one character.

Comment: What is the alternative way you want looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the *line.char* format for indexing the contents, along with a few variation (eg: “end”, *@x,y*) and modifiers like *wordstart*, *wordstart*, *wordend*, etc.

For the full definitive and complete definition of what is allowed, see the [indicies](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M24) section of the official tk text widget documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
text.tag_add("start", '1.1', '1.2')
text.tag_config("start", background= "black", foreground= "white")
```

Comment: maybe i'm wrong but this way i don't have an alternative way to index a character but i always use the raw.character method.

Comment: What's raw.character method do you used?

Comment: I may have something like this or not. def tag_alternating(event=None):
for i in range(0, 27, 2):
index = '1.' + str(i)
end = index + '+1c'
text.tag_add('even', index, end)

text.tag_configure('even', foreground='orange')

return "break"

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?